# touchesBegan method not being called from VideoPreviewLayer

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am trying to implement tap to focus on a camera view, however none of the override functions for a touch are being called. I have checked to make sure userInteractionEnabled = true for the view, and it is so. Here is my touchesBegan method:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        var anyTouch = touches.first as! UITouch
        var touchPercent = anyTouch.locationInView(self.view).x / screenWidth
        focusTo(Float(touchPercent))
    }
```

What I'm trying to interact with is a video preview layer which is created like so:

```
    videoPreviewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
    if let vpl = videoPreviewLayer {
        vpl.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
        vpl.frame = view.layer.bounds
        vpl.zPosition = -100
        view.layer.addSublayer(vpl)
    }
```

The preview and autofocus work fine, but anytime I try to tap on the screen to call touchesBegan, I get nothing.
Is there anything I'm completely missing when it comes to interacting, perhaps, with a sublayer?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend trying two things:

• Remove the zPosition (or at least make it positive) and see if touchesBegan is fired on tap.

• If that doesn't work try overriding hitTest:withEvent: and see if that fires instead.

If neither of those options works, then you probably have another view on-top of this one or your main window's size is 0,0 and no touches are being received at all.

Comment: I tried all of these things and nothing worked. I even tried to add another UIView and add it as a sublayer there, but it still didn't work. Would there be another reason why it's not being called?